# rich:listShuttle error when using complex object

Tags: java, jsf, seam

**WORKING:** This is my working rich:listShuttle when sourceValue and target value are List of strings.

**1. JSF Page**

```
<rich:listShuttle id="companyJurisdictionShutle"
            sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.statesList}"
            targetValue="#{companyAdminAction.selectedStates}"
            var="item" orderControlsVisible="false" fastOrderControlsVisible="false"
            sourceCaptionLabel="Available"
            targetCaptionLabel="Selected" styleClass="lishShuttle">
                 <rich:column>
                     #{item}
                 </rich:column>
</rich:listShuttle>
```

**2. Backing Bean**

```
//sourceValue                    
public List<String> getStatesList() {

    for (DMPJurisdiction dmpJurisdiction: jurisdictionList) {
        if(!statesList.contains(dmpJurisdiction.getJurisName())) {
            statesList.add(dmpJurisdiction.getJurisName());
        }
    }
    return statesList;
}

//targetValue
public List<String> getSelectedStates() {
    return selectedStates;
}
```

**3. Value Object**

```
public class DMPJurisdiction implements Serializable {

    /** serial version UID **/
    private final static Long serialVersionUID = 109892748283726L;

    /** jurisdiction id **/
    private Long jurisId;

    /** name **/
    private String jurisName;

    /** description **/
    private String jurisDescription;

    /** code **/
    private String jurisCode;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

**NOT-WORKING:** I changed the list shuttle, so that sourceValue and targetValue are list of complex object (DMPJurisdiction), not list of Strings as before. For which I wrote a converter.

**1. JSF Page**

```
<rich:listShuttle id="companyJurisdictionShutle"
      sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.jurisdictionList}"
      targetValue="#{companyAdminAction.targetJurisdictionList}"
      converter="#{dmpJurisdictionConverter}"
      var="item" orderControlsVisible="false" fastOrderControlsVisible="false"
      sourceCaptionLabel="Available"
      targetCaptionLabel="Selected" styleClass="lishShuttle">
             <rich:column>
                #{item.jurisName}
             </rich:column>
 </rich:listShuttle>
```

**2. Backing Bean**: Now return list of complex object DMPJurisdiction listed above.

```
//sourceValue
public List<DMPJurisdiction> getJurisdictionList() {
    return jurisdictionList;
}

//targetValue
    public List<DMPJurisdiction> getTargetJurisdictionList() {
    return targetJurisdictionList;
}
```

**3. Converter**

```
public class DmpJurisdictionConverter implements javax.faces.convert.Converter {

      public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
          List<DMPJurisdiction> dmpJurisdictionList = Cache.loadAllDmpJurisdictions();
            for (DMPJurisdiction dmpJurisdiction : dmpJurisdictionList) {
                if (dmpJurisdiction.getJurisName().equals(s)) {
                    return dmpJurisdiction;
                }
            }
            return null;
      }

      public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
          List<DMPJurisdiction> dmpJurisdictionList = Cache.loadAllDmpJurisdictions();
            for (DMPJurisdiction dmpJurisdiction : dmpJurisdictionList) {
                if (((DMPJurisdiction) o).getJurisName().equals(dmpJurisdiction.getJurisName())) {
                    return dmpJurisdiction.getJurisName();
                }
            }
            return null;
      }

}
```

**4. Error:**     `sourceId=accountWorkcaseOpenTabForm:addDmpCompanySubview:companyJurisdictionShutle[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /html/workcase/type/dmp/admin/AddCompany.xhtml @55,98 sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.jurisdictionList}": Property 'jurisdictionList' not writable on type java.util.List), detail=(javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /html/workcase/type/dmp/admin/AddCompany.xhtml @55,98 sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.jurisdictionList}": Property 'jurisdictionList' not writable on type java.util.List)] ||||`

**NOTE:** Just a side note, I am using the same dmpJurisdictionConverter successfully for selectOneMenu as shown below in a different **unrelated** JSF page.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{companyAdminAction.dmpJurisdiction}" converter="#{dmpJurisdictionConverter}">
                    <s:selectItems var="item" value="#{companyAdminAction.jurisdictionList}" label="#{item.jurisName}"
                                   hideNoSelectionLabel="true" noSelectionLabel="-- Select Jurisdiction --"/>
                    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{companyAdminAction.loadCompanyList()}"
                             reRender="dmpCompanies"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading  sourceValue="#{companyAdminAction.statesList}" using its getter **getStatesList**. It should be loaded separately, coz getters and setters are called multiple  times when page renders. I had to move loading statesList to another private method called during bean initialization.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the seam tag "<"s:convertEntity/>

it makes the conversion automatically, but the complex object must be an entity